# How does g++ linker resolve symbols among .so files

Tags: linker, g++

I understand object ordering is very important during linking. I've had a lot of headache before trying to get ld to resolve all symbols. This time ld didn't generate any error, but the output is wrong!

The project is big (50K+ lines of C++) and I can't generate a simplified version, so I'll try to describe what I encountered. Hopefully some expert can help me figure out.

```
g++ -o bad.out a.o b.o ... x.so y.so
g++ -o good.out a.o b.o ... y.so x.so
```

While good.out runs correctly, bad.out does not. Both x.so and y.so are provided by independent vendors, so their ordering should not matter. Here are more clues:

- a.o uses x.so
- b.o uses y.so
- a.o and b.o are independent, but they both use some common classes

The incorrect behavior manifests as a function OnRspLogin() never called back. This is a pure virtual function defined in y.so and implemented in b.o.  "grep OnRspLogin *.o *.so" only found match in y.so and b.o.

Apparently ld didn't resolved OnRspLogin() to the one in b.o, but which one did it resolve to? This worries me because linker didn't generate any error or warning.

I'm using gcc 4.4.7-4 on CentOS 6.5.

**EDIT:**
I found x.so and y.so both contain some common symbols (e.g. T TcpClient), so I guess linker picked x.so:TcpClient (instead of y.so:TcpClient) when resolving b.o:TcpClient.  While changing .so order may solve this problem, I'm afraid that linker may incorrectly resolve some other symbols in a.o. So is there anyway to tell the linker to resolve b.o using only y.so? Note that these .so files are provided by 3rd parties and I cannot change them.

Comment: Why do you think the function is not resolved? It is not really possible. If it's not getting called, the reason is that no code path calls it. The reason of *that* is probably x.so and y.so defining the same symbol, and the execution path thsat is taken depends on which version of that symbol gets used. By the way use `nm` to find symbols in object files, grepping objects directly is not informative.

Comment: I'm not saying that the function is not resolve; I said it didn't resolve to the right one. Indeed x.so and y.so contain common symbols. Is there anyway to tell ld which .so to use?

Comment: You have said there is only one function, meaning it's the right one. Having duplicate defs in several .so is a sign of trouble. You may not be able to use both .so simultaneously.

Comment: The first symbol loaded will be used throughout the program. This may or may not work in your situation. There is no way to tell other than by trying (and the answer is of course never definite).

Answer (score 1):

> I found x.so and y.so both contain some common symbols (e.g. T TcpClient)

That *is* a problem. If these symbols are supposed to be distinct, then you *can't* link these two libraries together -- they are not link compatible.

The *usual* way that vendors resolve these kind of problems is that they use distinct, vendor-specific prefix on all of their exported symbols (e.g. `vendorA_TcpClient`) and hide all other symbols.

> Note that these .so files are provided by 3rd parties and I cannot change them.

You can tell vendors that you can't use their library, unless they avoid defining symbols that aren't prefixed with their unique identifiers, and that you are not going to pay them unless they resolve this problem. Vendors often become quite responsive when do that.

Comment: Unfortunately vendors are not willing to change their .so files, because they have been released to many customers and QA is slow and risky. They just point finger at each other... Is their any bintool that can change symbol names?

Comment: Also for both vendors, although TcpClient appears in their .so files, it is something purely internal and never exposed at vender API.  I wonder if it matters at all since linker doesn't need to resolve it.

Comment: So they release libraries with internal symbols exposed, and then refuse to change them because their customers came to depend on these symbols they should have never seen in the first place? Nice.